# Rotating MongoDB collection efficiency

Tags: mongodb, performance, amazon-ec2, pymongo, database-performance

I have a MongoDB collection with approximately 20M objects in it.  Nightly, I am deleting a few fiscal months of data and replacing them with an import from CSV that uses PyMongo 3.0.something through Django.  This import is taking progressively longer as the database grows, and the server and process are starting to freeze occasionally.  The delete alone (6M rows) is starting to take ~14 minutes on our AWS servers.  I have indexed the delete by date, which is the appropriate field.

The query I am using to delete is:

```
db.getCollection("x").remove({date: {$gte: ISODate('2018-04-01')}})
```

The top-level Pymongo-integrated code, which may have a slight memory leak in it, is:

```
        while keep_fetch:
            raw_data = input_adapter.get_bulk() # in practice pulling 100,000 lines.
            if raw_data is None:
                raise Exception("bulk of data didn't return due to error,remove all last inserted docs")
            if raw_data == {} or raw_data == [] :
                log.debug("no more data to fetch")
                keep_fetch = False
                break
            #check for maintenance before insert first bulk
            if first_bulk == True: # first run-through, execute a delete if there is data.
                first_bulk = False
                #clean data in db to avoid duplicates
                if 'maintain_before_insert' in dir(output_adapter):
                    # Call function that cleans a time period's data from the database, and does other maintenance.
                    if output_adapter.maintain_before_insert() == False:
                        raise Exception("collection maintenance failed") 
            #Run an input adapter that formats the data into a list for insertion into Mongo.
            list_docs=input_adapter.format_data( raw_data )
            #get last date for next task to start from
            last_date = max(list_docs, key=lambda x:x['date'])['date']           
            output_adapter.store_bulk( list_docs ) # Mongo insert; it uses unmodified insert_many on the collection
            gc.collect()
```

I'm curious how I can speed the process up.  I have attempted bulk deletes with no improvement. I'm curious about expiring indexes, but I don't know whether expiring indexes can stop when our imports go stale (after 3 full months in arrears, it drops back to 2 and increases in size by one day nightly)

Increased AWS server size doesn't seem to affect process speed.  We're using a Django / Python server to send the delete and insert queries across, and the insert and delete processes seem to take about the same amount of time.

The server has no swap file; it is possible this is a server setup issue and therefore more appropriate to ServerFault, but since it was possible there was a code error I asked here.

I have done a significant amount of research and tried several possibilities. Will upgrading our PyMongo version help, possibly?

**Process Data, Process 1**

Performance Metrics on inserting a single (~ 675 MiB) CSV file:
Download of file from S3 bucket: .45 seconds
Removal of records (April-Unfinished June): 6,200,000 records removed in 14:18
Storage of records: 100,000 records inserted every 11-12 seconds between [note: first 100,000 is loaded into Python memory before delete, so the figures aren't exact] 20:15:21 and 20:32:11, for a total of 16:50 and 6,798,155 records added

Post-Process Table Size: Count: 19,367,660 ; Size: 7.5 GiB, Storage Size: 3.6 GiB, Indexes: 2, Total Index Size: 486.3 MiB

**Process Data, Process 2**

Performance Metrics on inserting a single (~ 225 MiB) CSV file:
Download of file from S3 bucket: .5 seconds
Removal of records (April-Unfinished June): 2,399,827 records removed in 2:51
Storage of records: 100,000 records inserted every 15'ish seconds between [note: first 100,000 is loaded into Python memory before delete, so the figures aren't exact] 20:37:10 and 20:43:37, for a total of 6:27 and 2,417,669 records added

Post-Process Table Size: Count: 6,332,293 ; Size: 2.5 GiB, Storage Size: 1.1 GiB, Indexes: 3, Total Index Size: 264.3 MiB

**Process Data, Process 3**

Performance Metrics on inserting a single (~ 20 MiB) CSV file:
Download of file from S3 bucket: .03 seconds
Removal of records (April-Unfinished June): 341,317 records removed in 22 seconds
Storage of records: 100,000 records inserted every 21'ish seconds between [note: first 100,000 is loaded into Python memory before delete, so the figures aren't exact] 20:44:46 and 20:45:17, for a total of 0:31 and 349,100 records added

Post-Process Table Size: Count: 811,200 ; Size: 145.7 MiB, Storage Size: 75.6 MiB, Indexes: 3, Total Index Size: 23.4 MiB

**Process Data, Process 4**

Performance Metrics on inserting a single (~ 20 MiB) CSV file:
Download of file from S3 bucket: .5 seconds
Removal of records (April-Unfinished June): 352,010 records removed in :09
Storage of records: 100,000 records inserted every 8'ish seconds between [note: first 100,000 is loaded into Python memory before delete, so the figures aren't exact] 20:46:05 and 20:46:38, for a total of 0:33 and 357,040 records added

Post-Process Table Size: Count: 821,924 ; Size: 217.7 MiB, Storage Size: 95.3 MiB, Indexes: 3, Total Index Size: 22.9 MiB

**Note**

The performance seems extremely non-linear on delete.  It looks very much like I should be batching the deletes somehow before re-indexing and I am not; can I somehow 'lock' this collection for the delete and additions (it is unused except by this process) or create a single transaction that prevents the index from re-calculating mid-process so that it recalculates afterwards?

Information requested:

1) Our servers are EC2 instances, running 18.04 on the Django / Python side and 14.04 on the Mongo side.  The Mongo version is 3.4.3, Wired Tiger engine.

2) I have checked the explain() output and the JSON output looks like this:

```
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH", 
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN", 
            "keyPattern" : {
                "date" : -1.0
            }, 
            "indexName" : "date_-1", 
            "isMultiKey" : false, 
            "multiKeyPaths" : {
                "date" : [

                ]
            }, 
            "isUnique" : false, 
            "isSparse" : false, 
            "isPartial" : false, 
            "indexVersion" : 2.0, 
            "direction" : "forward", 
            "indexBounds" : {
                "date" : [
                    "[new Date(9223372036854775807), new Date(1522540800000)]"
                ]
            }
        }
```

My conclusion is that the index is working.

3) The 'date' field is indexed, as is the 'id' field

4) The current hardware on the Mongo side is a t2.small or t2.medium Mongo server.  Upgrading the instance from t1 to t2 seems to have had little to no effect on the delete speed, although the medium servers aren't freezing, which is nice.

5) The volume for each drive is a cloud-based gp2 AWS instance.  This has a theoretical 160 MiB/s limit, the rows I'm adding are totaling to 7.5GiB, and the index size is 486.3MB.

Comment: Is the collection sharded? If not that may be worth trying. What MongoDB version do you have and what storage engine?

Comment: Have you tried to read the `explain` output to check, whether the index is really used?

Comment: I don't believe upgrading pymongo will help since this is a server issue. Some questions: 1) What are your indexes, 2) What query you use to delete documents, 3) What is your hardware spec.

Comment: I think the server is underprovisioned. It is possible that you're reaching the IOPS limit of your AWS instances, and are being throttled (hence the freezes). Checking the AWS metric (e.g. CPU steal, or similar) should confirm if this is the case or not.

Comment: The CPU is not overloaded.  The total amount of data going through the pipe is actually comparatively small, I believe.  I'll spend some time adding my volume data and actual storage / delete figures.

Comment: Note: this system is on an SSD drive, but the OS is set up to have no swap file.  Will that slow insert / delete down?  The server itself, at rest, has 3.7G free memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to delete using de default index **_id**, because this object marks the date when the document was inserted and it's unique.

You can use a mongo function to convert the objectID to date and filter the data you want to remove.

https://steveridout.com/mongo-object-time/

I send you some shell script functions to manage with dates using the mentioned function to filter:

```
# Funcion getObjectId
function getObjectId
{
    local date="$1"

    # JavaScript code to calculate ObjectIds of the dates
    printf 'var objectIdFromDate = function (date) { if(typeof date === "string") date = new Date(date); return ObjectId( Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000" ); };\nobjectIdFromDate("%s")\n' $date > file.js

    result=$(mongo $MONGODB_AUTH -u $MONGODB_USER -p $MONGODB_PASS < file.js | grep ObjectId | awk -F '"' {'print $2'})

    echo $result
}


#Funcion to get the initial and final dates of the last week
function calculateDates {

local dbname="$1"
local limitDays=$2

# Initial variables of the function
currentDate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00.000Z')
currentDay=$(date '+%d')
currentMonth=$(date '+%m')
currentYear=$(date '+%Y')

# We check if the day and the month are less than 10, verifing the first digit is 0
if [ ${currentDay:0:1} -eq 0 ]; then
        currentDay=${currentDay:1:1}
fi

if [ ${currentMonth:0:1} -eq 0 ]; then
        currentMonth=${currentMonth:1:1}
fi

# If the current day is less or iqutal to 7 we have to calculate one week back getting a day from provious month
if [ $currentDay -le $limitDays ]; then

        if [ $currentMonth -eq 1 ]; then
                previousMonth=12
                let previousYear=$currentYear-1

        else
                let previousMonth=$currentMonth-1
                previousYear=$currentYear
        fi

        if [ $previousMonth -eq 2 ]; then
                maxMonthDays=28
                let var=7-$currentDay
                let previousDay=$maxMonthDays-$var
        else
                if [ $previousMonth -eq 4 ] || [ $previousMonth -eq 6 ] || [ $previousMonth -eq 9 ] || [ $previousMonth -eq 11 ]; then
                        maxMonthDays=30
                        let var=$limitDays-$currentDay
                        let previousDay=$maxMonthDays-$var
                else
                        maxMonthDays=31
                        let var=$limitDays-$currentDay
                        let previousDay=$maxMonthDays-$var
                fi
        fi

else
        let previousDay=$currentDay-$limitDays
        previousMonth=$currentMonth
        previousYear=$currentYear
fi

# Updating format of the date
if [ $previousDay -lt 10 ]; then
        previousDay="0$previousDay"
fi

if [ $previousMonth -lt 10 ]; then
        previousMonth="0$previousMonth"
fi

# We get the previous date in format yyyy/mm/dd
previousDate=`echo "$previousYear-$previousMonth-$previousDay'T00:00:00.000Z'" | tr -d "'"`

objectId_fd=`getObjectId $currentDate`
objectId_rd=`getObjectId $previousDate`

# We construct part of the query with updated dates to execute tha backup
printf '{ "_id": { "$gte": { "$oid": "%s"} , "$lte": { "$oid": "%s"} }  }' $objectId_rd $objectId_fd > query.json

}
```

I hope this helps.